# Scrape 2 inner texts within div as one value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following html

```
<div class="price-block__highlight"><span class="promo-price" data- 
test="price">102,
<sup class="promo-price__fraction" data-test="price-fraction">99</sup>
</span>

</div>
```

I want to print the price of this html without comma, so 
print price should result in:
102.99

I have the following code

```
pricea = page_soup.find("div", {"class":"price-block__highlight"})
price = str(pricea.text.replace('-','').replace(',','.').strip())
print price
```

This however results in:

```
 102.
  99
```

When writing in a csv it creates multiple rows. How to get both numbers in one value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are using `bs4`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<div class="price-block__highlight"><span class="promo-price" data-
test="price">102,
<sup class="promo-price__fraction" data-test="price-fraction">99</sup>
</span>

</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

price_div = soup.find("div", {"class": 'price-block__highlight'})

texts = [x.strip() for x in price_div.text.split(',')]

print('.'.join(texts))
```

**Output**

102.99